# WPF AvalonDock ExpressionDark

Tags: wpf, themes, avalondock

I have been working with WPF and AvalonDock and would like to apply the AvalonDock.theme.ExpressionDark.

However, when I applied this theme, the docking direction indicator will not show up.

If I just apply the AvalonDock normally (without applying any extra theme but using the default one), it will show a docking direction indicator when I drag out a DockablePane or DocumentPane.

However, this docking direction indicator doesn't show up after I applied the ExpressionDark theme.

Does anyone know why? and how can I solve it?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ExpressionDark theme actually does not support any docking indicators as can be seen in Expression Blend. So this is done on purpose, you can say also the docking behavior is defined in the theme.

If you still want to enable the docking indicators you will need to combine both themes (the default one with the expression dark theme) in some way which might be a bit tricky.

Hope this helps.